# Why are the last U.S. states to get their votes in all swing states?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, ballot

As of writing this, all the remaining states that still have votes coming in are extremely close competitions between the presidential candidates.

I don't think that's a coincidence as I recall it happening in the past. Are votes easier to count and submit if the state is less disputed, or **why are the last states to get their votes in such close competitions?**

Answer (score 8):

One answer I just heard from a friend on social media:

The last states to have their votes in are not necessarily swing states. The results reported in media are statistical projections. States with a close competition take longer to project, as differences of a few percentage points are practically even. States that have a clearer difference are easier to project earlier with the same level of confidence. That's why the states the media is focusing on toward the end of the count are the swing states with close competitions.

Comment: Yes.  For instance, California was called exactly when the polls closed, before almost any votes were officially counted.

Comment: And then there's the 2000 election, where several networks called Florida for Gore before the polls had even closed, only to retract it later.  (After several weeks of recounts and lawsuits, the final certified result was that Bush won the state with a margin of 537 votes, out of nearly 6 million ballots cast.)  This incident seems to have made the media more cautious about reporting results from swing states.